# Linux to windows compatibility with dev/urandom,Is there a better approach?

Tags: php, linux, windows, compatibility, csrf-protection

Hi i want to use a package called [Kunststube-CSRFP](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP/blob/master/CryptoProvider.php) on my project

Problem is the package will throw an exception on windows machines because dev/random is not legit for Windows..

The function causes the exception is below..

```
protected function getRandomHexStringFromDevRandom($length) {
        static $sources = array('/dev/urandom', '/dev/random');
        foreach ($sources as $source) {
            if (@is_readable($source)) {
                return bin2hex(file_get_contents($source, false, null, -1, $length / 2));
            }
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('No system source for randomness available.');
    }
```

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) one can also use mcrypt_create_iv function..
And here is my approach to solve this compatibility problem..

```
protected function getRandomHexStringFromDevRandom($length) {
        //static $sources = array('/dev/urandom', '/dev/random');
        srand(time());
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_RAND);

        if($iv){
          return bin2hex($iv);
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('No system source for randomness available.');
    }
```

I don't have a linux machine to test if both function's returns similar outputs..

### My question: is this solution ok? or is there a better way?Thanks for your helps..

Php version : 5.5.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to generate random strings for two reason:

1. As safe as using `/dev/random`
2. Can be use in either Windows or Linux

But you have to enable the OpenSSL extension in PHP otherwise you will get error.

Code:

```
protected function getRandomHexStringFromDevRandom($length) {
    if(!extension_loaded("openssl")){
        throw new \RuntimeException("OpenSSL extension not loaded");
    }
    $cstrong = false;
    while(!$cstrong) {
        $rand = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $cstrong);
    }
    return $rand;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to try another algorithm if the first one wasn't cryptographically secure? Won't it just do the same thing as the first time and enter an infinite loop?

Comment: @Septagram just tried with a custom script which runs the function for 10B times in a for loop. There is no failure, not even one time.